# sympy using nsimplify with symbols

Tags: python, sympy, simplify

In sympy, I want to simplify a long expression, like:

```
70*x*y/33 + 35*x**2/33 - 70*y**2/33 + 35/99
```

to:

```
(3*sqrt(2)/2)*x*y + (3*sqrt(2)/4)*x**2 - (3*sqrt(2)/2)*y**2 + sqrt(2)/4
```

I tried using `nsimplify`, but dont get the desired result.

In detail:

`nsimplify((70/33), [sqrt(2)], tolerance=10**-2)` is `3*sqrt(2)/2`

but

`nsimplify((70/33)*x, [sqrt(2)], tolerance=10**-2)` is `70*x/33`

I've tried declaring the symbols as positive but it didn't do the trick.

What's happening here? How can I get my desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with replace:

```
In [12]: e = 70*x*y/33 + 35*x**2/33 - 70*y**2/33 + S(35)/99

In [13]: e
Out[13]: 
    2                2     
35⋅x    70⋅x⋅y   70⋅y    35
───── + ────── - ───── + ──
  33      33       33    99

In [14]: e.replace(lambda e: e.is_Rational, lambda e: nsimplify(e, [sqrt(2)], tolerance=1e-2))
Out[14]: 
      2                    2     
3⋅√2⋅x    3⋅√2⋅x⋅y   3⋅√2⋅y    √2
─────── + ──────── - ─────── + ──
   4         2          2      4
```